# Counting number of statuses in group concat row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've taken over a project that is a real mess so I've left with bad code structure that is forcing me to basically program in `SQL`. So changing the way of calculating this is for now not an option.

I have `$sqlAdd` variable that i need to populate in function and then concatenate that to main query to count number of lost tickets.

Main query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num_tickets, SUM(t.total_amount) as total_payin, SUM(t.total_payout) as total_payout
FROM t WHERE t.tickettime BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo' AND t.bsid = $bsID
$sqlAdd";
```

So $sqlAdd is getting from another function

```
$sqlAdd = getSqlAdd();
```

And in that function i have this:

```
$sqlAdd = " AND 'WON' NOT IN (
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tr.ticketstatus)
           FROM tr INNER JOIN m ON tr.ticketid = m.ticketid
           WHERE tr.ticketid = t.ticketid GROUP BY m.ticket_groupid
           )
       AND 'PAYEDOUT' NOT IN (
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tr.ticketstatus)
           FROM tr INNER JOIN m ON tr.ticketid = m.ticketid
           WHERE tr.ticketid = t.ticketid GROUP BY m.ticket_groupid
           )
       AND 'CLOSED' NOT IN (
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tr.ticketstatus)
           FROM tr INNER JOIN m ON tr.ticketid = m.ticketid
           WHERE tr.ticketid = t.ticketid GROUP BY m.ticket_groupid
           )
       AND 'OPEN' NOT IN (
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tr.ticketstatus)
           FROM tr INNER JOIN m ON tr.ticketid = m.ticketid
           WHERE tr.ticketid = t.ticketid GROUP BY m.ticket_groupid
           )";
```

GROUP_CONCAT(tr.ticketstatus) is getting me these rows when i execute it

```
CLOSED,CLOSED,CLOSED
PAYEDOUT,PAYEDOUT
CLOSED,CLOSED
WON,LOST
LOST,WON,WON,WON,WON,WON
CLOSED,CLOSED
LOST,LOST,WON
WON,WON,WON,LOST,LOST,WON,WON
LOST
```

I just want to count rows that have only LOST status in it. So the result should be 1. But i keep getting 7. It it counting every LOST status in results.

Comment: Please edit your question and include table aliases so we know where the values are coming from.  Also, I would advise you to avoid `NATURAL JOIN`; it is a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you i've done that and removed unnecessary joins also

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_tickets, SUM(t.total_amount) as total_payin,
       SUM(t.total_payout) as total_payout
FROM t
WHERE t.tickettime BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND
      '$dateTo' AND t.bsid = $bsID AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tr NATURAL JOIN
                       m NATURAL JOIN
                       tg
                  WHERE tr.ticketid = t.ticketid AND
                        tr.ticketstatus IN ('WON', 'PAYEDOUT', 'CLOSED', 'OPEN')
                 );
```

Some notes:

- `GROUP_CONCAT()` is not appropriate for this type of comparison.  In SQL, you don't convert lists to strings and then do comparisons -- at least if you want performance.
- You should avoid `NATURAL JOIN`.  A small change to any of the tables can totally change the semantics of the query.  In addition, it is unclear what the `JOIN` keys are.  I would recommend `USING` instead.
- You might want `tr.ticketstatus NOT IN ('LOST')` in the subquery.

Comment: This query is still getting me 7 as num_tickets. The problem here is that relationship between t and tr tables is 1 to many. So one ticketid in tr can have multiple statuses depending on which roundid it is.

Answer (score 0):

So i've wrote very ugly query that is probably slow but its working i'm getting results that i need.

```
$sql = " AND ticket_groupid IN ( 
  SELECT tg FROM t as tt 
  NATURAL JOIN tr NATURAL JOIN m 
  WHERE tt.tickettime BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo' AND tt.bsid = $bsid
  AND 'LOST' IN ( 
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tr.ticketstatus) 
     FROM tr NATURAL JOIN m as mm 
     WHERE mm.ticket_groupid = m.ticket_groupid 
     ) 
 GROUP BY mm.ticket_groupid )"
```